# Create VB6 Installer with Database & DSN

Tags: sql, vb6, installation, package, dsn

I have created a project in VB6 With SQL 2000 using ODBC DSN. Now i want to create a Software installer which can install software, install SQL 2000 and Create DSN in one install wizard. Currently i am installing SQL 2000 then creating DSN then installing software manually.

Is there any software or program which can make a single installer for all process.
I have seen some installer which is making installer only for my application (Not installing SQL & creating DSN) but this not my requirement b'cause i can already make setup using Package & Deployment wizard.

Thanks,

Yusuf

Comment: We use Inno: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Comment: This is only for my application only. Not for my requirement.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. you want an installer that can do some custom things - Inno can do that. We install SQL Server 2008 Express as part of our install

Comment: Yes really this is i need, i need a installer which can do custom thing. How can you install SQL Server with Inno? can you explain?

Comment: You provide Inno with a list of files that you want installing, where to install them, and any flags that need to be set. In addition it has a Pascal compiler that allows you to do anything. You will have to 'get into it' though. One or two paragraphs will not explain enough. I suspect that is true of all installers one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish what you need. You can use something as complex as Install Shield to interact with the ODBC API or you can simply use Visual Basic 6 code to create the DSN entry.

It sounds like the VB6 will be the easiest for you:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184608